# How to find title="xyz" element with Selenium (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to click an element with Selenium, that has a specific title attribute. I have tired do use an `xpath` before, however, the problem is that there are two buttons on the website with the same `xpath`. If one button is active, it has the same `xpath` as the other when its active and vice versa.

The only thing that differentiates these two buttons in the title attribute.

```
<a class="qPKfxd" href="SOME LINK" title="List">
```

Basically I am trying to only click that element if the title is `"List"`.

Has anyone got an idea of how to specify that with Selenium?

Please let me know if you need to view more code.

Comment: you can it out from browser dev tools by right click on the element -> copy selector/ copy xpath

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can locate an element by attribute.

`xpath`:

```
//a[@title="List"]
```

`css_selector`

```
[title="List"]
```

Comment: Nice one! That has worked. Thank you very much - have a good day